# Oracle XE 12c won't configure - getting the "port 5,500 in use" error message

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, installation

I have the infamous "port 5,500 in use" error message while trying to start/configure Oracle XE 12c.

I have searched for this problem and every solution I have found has been the same - make sure the hostname matches between `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts`. I have done that, using `grep -w` to confirm the strings are the same, and they are, but the problem is not resolved.

- `/etc/hostname`

  ```
  iv4x.rdu.csb
  ```
- `/etc/hosts`

  ```
  127.0.0.1   iv4x.rdu.csb localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
  ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
  ```

The difference I see with the above is I didn't have a non-loopback IP address in `/etc/hosts`.  I attempted using those addresses reported by "ip a", but all of those failed as well, e.g.:

- `/etc/hosts`

  ```
  127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
  ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
  192.168.122.1   iv4x.rdu.csb
  ```

I should add that I have used `netstat` to search for anything using that port and I found nothing. I have also tried configuring Oracle to use different ports and received the same error message for any port that I tried.

I would appreciate any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: If the error says "port is in use", why are you concerned about the hostname?

Comment: Because all of the answers I was able to find cite the hostname being out of sync between /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts (my second paragraph). The fixes proposed in those answers did not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with the assistance of our DBA team.

The problem was I using a fully qualified hostname in the /etc/hosts file. I had interpreted the solutions I found that cited "hostnames must match" to include the domain name as well.

If your hostname is xxxx.yyyy.zzzz, then you add just "xxxx" to /etc/hosts, per the instructions provided:

127.0.0.1    xxxx.yyyy.zzzz    *anything-else*   **xxxx**

In my case, I added just "iv4x" to the loopback line.

Comment: Actually, you should NOT put the actual hostname "on the loopback line", associating it with 127.0.0.1.  You should put it on a line associating it with a/the actual routable ip address.  And on that, I always put both the fully qualified hostname as well as the short name, ie: '192.168.56.1 myhost.mydomain myhost'.

Comment: I agree except that I don't have a static IP address - this runs on my laptop as a sandbox, its not a "standard" installation.

Comment: I never run a database directly on my laptop or workstation.  I always create a vm (using oracle's VirtualBox) and install oracle on the VM.  That way I get to treat the system that is running the database exactly like I would any server in my locked-door, lights-out data center.

Comment: If only my laptop had enough oomph for that. It can barely handle an external monitor. Fortunately, my need is for creating tables and exporting DDL, changes to even our dev database requires a ticket and time; its part of a more complex dev environment.

Comment: How much memory does your laptop have? How much free space on the disk? What CPU?  I'd be shocked if any relatively modern laptop were unable to run a minimal VM running Oracle on Linux.